# Why does join() behave the way it does in this example?

Tags: javascript

Why does `join()` behave the way it does in the following example?

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(times){
   return new Array(times).join(this)
}
'a'.repeat(3); // 'aa'
```

Per my understanding, it should be `aaa`, but instead I'm getting `aa`.

Why is this?

Comment: that's how join() works...

Comment: yes the join(), working here for that behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Array(3).join('a')
```

You are creating an array with three empty elements here (which are converted to empty strings for joining), and join them together with `a` in between the three – so you end up with `'' + 'a' + '' + 'a' + ''`, which is `aa`.